# Update target when value is checked as invalid in source's set clause

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm using MVVM in WPF.

I try to bind the SelectedIndex of a ListView to view model with TwoWay mode, code like this:

XAML:

```
<ListView  SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=CurrentIndex, Mode=TwoWay>
    ...
</ListView>
```

ViewModel:

```
public DemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ...
   public int CurrentIndex
   {
       get
       {
           return _currentIndex;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value == _currentIndex)
               return;
           try
           {
               DoSomething(value);
           }
           catch(DataInvalidException e)
           {
              OnPropertyChanged("CurrentIndex");
              MessageBox.Show(e.message);
              return;
           }

           _currentIndex = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("CurrentIndex");
           }
       }
   }
   int _currentIndex;
}
```

It almost works, but when it catches the DataInvalidException and return, I wish to keep the SelectedIndex to its old value. So I call `OnPropertyChanged()` without updating `_currentIndex`, such that the binding target `ListView.SelectedIndex` should be changed back to original value. But it didn't.

Any help will be appreciate, and forgive my half-baked English.

Comment: Your code should work. How do you know that `SelectedIndex` is changed and not set to old value?

Comment: Thanks for updating the problem. The scene is, when a `ListViewItem` was clicked, the `SelectedIndex` was changed, since it's `TwoWay` binding, it ran to the get clause of `CurrentIndex`, then I call OnPropertyChanged() without updating `_currentIndex` to make the `SelectedIndex` to the old value, but it didn't because that the `SelectedItem` is different before it was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the ListView with ItemsSource to ObervableCollection / CollectionView in your VM and SelectedItem to DataTypeSelectedItem Property in your VM.

For example View:

```
 <ListView Name="ListViewWithCustomItems" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomItem}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CustomItems}">
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomItem> CustomItems
{
     get { return _customItems; }
     private set
     {
        if (Equals(value, _customItems)) return;                
        _customItems= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CustomItems");
      }
}

public CustomItem SelectedCustomItem
{
  get { return _selectedCustomItem }
  private set
   {
     if (Equals(value, _selectedCustomItem )) return;
     try
     {
        DoSomething(value); 
        //if you need the index and not the model do one way-Binding to the index too
      }
      catch(DataInvalidException e)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(e.message);
       return;
      }
      _selectedCustomItem = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCustomItem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you advice, bind to SelectedItem will be better. But for this  occasion, why make `oldvalue = value`?

Comment: I've done a copy&paste error, but already corrected it in the answer to: _currentIndex = oldvalue; for the Case, that DoSomething( ) will change _currentIndex.

Comment: oh, now it is more that i intended.